# Getting unique values from an array with words containing diacritics in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, unicode, diacritics, uniq

How can I get `uniq` values from an array by discounting the presence of the same words without the proper diacritics?

Right now it works like this:

```
["Poznan", "Poznań", "Gdańsk"].uniq 
=> ["Poznan", "Poznań", "Gdańsk"]
```

And this is what I want to achieve:

```
["Poznan", "Poznań", "Gdańsk"].uniq 
=> ["Poznań", "Gdańsk"]
```

Comment: What should `["Poznań", "Poznañ", "Pôznan"].uniq` return?

Comment: Poznań, Im particulary interested in Polish words.

Comment: Well, you can start with specifying the rules.

Comment: Based upon what I just learned from a quick Google search, the lower-case letters in the Polish alphabet differ from the English alphabet in two ways: 1) the former does not have the English letters "q",  "v" and "x"; and 2) the former has additional letters "ą",  "ć",  "ę", "ł", "ń", "ó", "ś", "ź" and "ż".  Suppose we were to download an English to Polish dictionary and set about attempting to find a Polish word that differs from a give English word `word` according to a set of matching rules. If `word` is found in the Polish dictionary we evidently have a match. (cont.)

Comment: ...If `word` matches `/[qvx]/` it would seem there is no similar Polish word (unless the rules show "q", "v" and "x" map in Polish letters.)  The remaining case to check is to see if there is a word in the Polish dictionary for every combination of character substitutions specified by the rules. For example, if `word #=> "conifer"` one presumably would have to consider all combinations of substituting one or more values for keys in the hash `{ "c"=>"ć", "o"=>"ó", "n"=>"ń", "f"=>"ł", "e"=>"ę",  }`, of which there are `2**5-1 #=> 31`.

Comment: I think its not neccesery. Just ó change to o; ń change to n; ż, ź to z ; then get uniq and return one that had polish letters, if there are 2 words that have polish letters return 2, its seems they are diffrent words

Comment: I'm at a disadvantage in that I don't know Polish, but does the Polish alphabet not have both "o" and ó"? If so, how would a machine know which it would be in the Polish word? A reminder: to notify SO members that you have a left a comment, include their username in their comment.

Comment: I mean when póznań Will translate to poznan and poznań will result in poznan, if there are at least 2 diffrent words pointing to one then it needs to be consider not same. I guess

Comment: Your last comment seems to support the algorithm I suggested, though I might be wrong. I need to [polish up](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/polish-up) on my Polish.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland this searching for uniqness is for purpose if someone didnt use Latin chars in word, therefore it seems like diffrent word. If i Will normalize it to non Latin I can find which words with Latin are adequate. Its True that without dictionary its hard to guess. So I think i should prioritize just first match maybe and second treat as diffrent

Answer (score 3):

You could normalize the Unicode to NFKD form to separate the accent from the underlying characters and then remove the accents. That would transform `'Poznań'` to `'Poznan'` while leaving `'Poznan'` alone. Then use the block form of [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
array = %w[Poznan Poznań Gdańsk]
array.uniq { |s| s.unicode_normalize(:nfkd).gsub(/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/, '') }
# ["Poznan", "Gdańsk"]
```

Note that `Poznan` is chosen rather than `Poznań`. If you have a preference for one form of a word over another then you can use the normalizing and accent removal to compare the words and implement your own version of `uniq` that prioritizes your preferred form.

Comment: yes. this is what I was looking for, then I need to create Hash that will register which latin word was translated to which non-latin word and then just use this as dictionary. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about use of **[I18n.transliterate](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/2.3.17/I18n.transliterate)** : `Transliterates` `UTF-8` characters to `ASCII`. By default this method will transliterate only Latin strings to an ASCII approximation:

```
> require "i18n"
> I18n.config.available_locales = :en
> ["Poznan", "Poznań", "Gdańsk"].map{|e| I18n.transliterate(e)}.uniq
#=> ["Poznan", "Gdansk"]
```

Comment: Great answer also. Do you have trick to return Latin over nonlatin?

Comment: @sonic : no idea for reverse, need to explore this method